# dropdown list on post back and form validation on post back

Tags: asp.net-core-7.0

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and the latest version ASP.NET Core 7.

I have 2 dropdown lists on my form, let's call them `dropdown list 1` and `dropdown list 2`.

`Dropdown list 2` is populated based on the selection of `dropdown list 1`. `Dropdown list 1` does a post back to populate `dropdown list 2`.

I also have a submit button on the form, which must validate that `dropdown list 1` was selected before submitting the form. I don't get this part because on post back I am using it to populate `dropdown list 2`. When clicking on the submit button it must validate that `dropdown list 1` has a value selected.

This is part of what my view looks like:

```
@model BookingsReportViewModel

<form asp-controller="Report" asp-action="Bookings" method="post">
    <div class="mb-3 row">
        <label for="EventId" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label fw-bold">Event</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select asp-for="EventId" asp-items="@Model.Events" class="form-select" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 row">
        <label for="VenueId" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label fw-bold">Venue</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select asp-for="VenueId" asp-items="@Model.Venues" class="form-select">
                <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="my-4" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generate Excel Report</button>
</form>
```

My action methods look something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Bookings()
{
    BookingsReportViewModel viewModel = new();
    viewModel.Events = await PopulateEvents();

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Bookings(BookingsReportViewModel viewModel)
{
    viewModel.Events = await PopulateEvents();

    if (viewModel.EventId != null)
    {
        viewModel.Venues = await PopulateVenuesForEvent(viewModel.EventId.Value);
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

I don't understand where I need to do the validation that `dropdown list 1` has a value selected?

I want to do it like above, server sided and with **NO** Ajax.

Comment: `if (viewModel.EventId != null)` - Is this not already performing the validation you're looking for?  The data posted by the form should be in the `viewModel` instance.  Can you clarify what specifically isn't working as expected when you debug this?

Comment: Yes it works as what you describe, but I don't want it like that when you click the button. I want to do normal validation, same as above but I just want it to display an error message "Please select a value" or what ever. I can do the validation, no problem, I just don't know where to put it? The button will then retrieve the dropdown values and submit the form to the database. I only want the error message to display when clicking the button.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal validation" and how does that differ from what you have?  To "display an error message" are you just asking how to include a value from the controller method which can be used in the view?  Are you familiar with things like `ViewBag` or `TempData`?  For example, in the controller you could do: `ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "some string";`  Then in the view you can check if `@ViewBag.ErrorMessage` contains a value and display that value.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Let me rephrase in short. The post back is supposed to do 2 things, currently it is only doing 1 thing, namely populating dropdown list 2 based on what is selected in dropdown list 1. Now when this is done, I have to click the button to take the values selected and do something with it. Now when you click the button, it must validate if a value in dropdown list 1 is selected. If not display a error message. How do I distinguish in the post of it is button submit or a change in the dropdown list value?

Comment: *"How do I distinguish in the post of it is button submit or a change in the dropdown list value?"* - Since you've designed both operations to post the same form to the same controller action, there really **isn't** much of a difference.  One possible approach could be to give a `name` and `value` attribute to the submit button and add that property to the view model.  *Maybe* (you'll need to test this) that value won't be included when you do `this.form.submit()` in the JavaScript, but will be included when clicking the submit button.